Databricks SQL REST API w/ Javascript
need to use Databricks SQL Statement Execution API w/ Javascript (see example post )
For some reason, Curl Works, Python works, but Javascript fails.
This works : 
(curl)

curl --request POST \
https://adb-5750xxxxxxx.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/sql/statements/ \
--header "Authorization: Bearer dapi5c3xxxxxxx" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{
"warehouse_id": "368axxxxxxx",
"catalog": "main",
"schema": "myschema",
"statement": "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1"
}'

This works : 
(python)

import os
import requests
import json


host = "https://"+DATABRICKS_HOST+"/api/2.0/sql/statements"

# sql query
warehouse_id = DATABRICKS_WAREHOUSE_ID
query = "SELECT * from mytable limit 1"

query_resp = requests.post(url=host, headers={"Authorization": "Bearer " + DATABRICKS_API_TOKEN}, data=json.dumps({"statement": query, "warehouse_id": warehouse_id, "catalog": "main","schema": "myschema"}))

print(query_resp.status_code)
print(query_resp.json())

This does NOT work :
(javascript)

displayHTML(f"""
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h3>Log</h3>
<textarea id="log" rows="10" cols="200" readonly></textarea>

<script>

const baseUrl = "https://adb-575xxxx.azuredatabricks.net/api/2.0/sql/statements/";
const warehouseId = "368xxxxx";
const token = "dapixxxxxx";
const catalog = "main";
const schema = "ocealia";
const statement = "SELECT * FROM cereales LIMIT 1";

const fetchData = async () => {{
const url = `${{baseUrl}}`;
const data = {{
warehouse_id: warehouseId,
catalog: catalog,
schema: schema,
statement: statement,
}};

const options = {{
method: "POST",
headers: {{
Authorization: `Bearer ${{token}}`,
"Content-Type": "application/json",
}},
body: JSON.stringify(data),
}};

try {{
const response = await fetch(url, options);
if (!response.ok) {{
throw new Error(`Error fetching data: ${{response.status}}`);
}}
const jsonData = await response.json();
logMessage("Results:", jsonData);
}} catch (error) {{
logMessage( error);
}}
}};
 
function logMessage(message) {{
var logArea = document.getElementById('log');
logArea.value += message + "\\n";
logArea.scrollTop = logArea.scrollHeight; // Scroll to the bottom
}}

fetchData();
</script>

</body>
</html>
""")


For some obscure reason it throws :
TypeError: Failed to fetch

It is interesting to note that when calling the clusters list GET request, it DOES succeed.
let url = `https://${{DATABRICKS_HOST}}/api/2.0/clusters/list`

For some reason this one works but the POST sql statement fails
Any help is truly appreciated.
EDIT 
this is just a mockup prototype that is run directly from a databricks notebook. I just want to validate that it works properly. of course I'll put everything in environment variables and use secrets in the final version, provided my setup works.

My recollection is that the APIs for Azure Databricks are protected by a CORS policy as the intended use cases for these endpoints do not include external third party web application frontends. This itself is also a terrible idea considering the token you’re baking into your code in plaintext (readable by all users of your application) is not intended to be disclosed as such. If you really want to do this, you could create a CORS proxy that bypasses this restriction, but you open your users to a host of vulnerabilities this way. I would encourage you to rethink your design here.

Now that I am recalling more, your token prepended with the strong dapi is a Personal Access Token (PAT). It is not intended for use in this way. From Microsoft’s docs: “Be sure to save the copied token in a secure location. Do not share your copied token with others.” Again, this type of setup is not advisable and disclosing your token can lead to devastating side effects, up to and including a full compromise of your Databricks account.

@esqew this is just a mockup prototype that is run directly from a databricks notebook. I just want to validate that it works properly. of course I'll put everything in environment variables and use secrets in the final version, provided my setup works. I've added an edit to the post

@esqew yes I've read about CORS but that is definitely way out of my alley, I'm not a front person at all. May I kindly ask you what would be the proper way of doing such things ? I mean, the example code and docuementation from Databricks SQL Statement Execution API uses that token API as well, this ruins the whole point of such a feature if it can't be used in web application (am I missing something ? TYSM)

Usually these requests to this API would be executed by backend server application (which is not subject to CORS, as you found in your Python example), not a browser user agent. Your frontend would communicate with this backend, which would effectively proxy the requests to the Azure Databricks API on behalf of your users’ browsers. This also enables security in that your web application backend can be assigned a service principal identity while implementing whatever authorization/authentication logic you already use for your individual users.

If your code is compatible with Node.js you should probably use the Databricks SDK for Node.js / Javascript rather than integrate the APIs directly: https://docs.databricks.com/en/dev-tools/nodejs-sql-driver.html
